# jQuery Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: +

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that is creating some issues with `jQuery` when a  `"+"` symbol is being passed as part of a string.

Here is an example:

```js
var ssArr = ["First/","Second /","Third+"];
if(ssArr !== null) {
  $.each(ssArr, function(ind, val){
    if(val !== ''){
      val = val.replace(/ /g, '').replace('/', '');
      console.log(val);
      $('.tstNavLi' + val).addClass('active');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  color: coral;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 3px solid coral;
  margin: 20px 0
}

ul li.active {
  color: blue;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <ul>
    <li class="tstNavLiFirst">First</li>
    <li class="tstNavLiSecond">Second</li>
    <li class="tstNavLiThird+">Third+</li>
  </ul>
  
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get this to work? This is part of a cms/shopping system and the `"+"` symbol is used quite frequently, so I cannot change the `"+"` for some other symbol.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider are those really `class`es or should they be something like `data-label`s?

Because if they're not actually CSS classes, you can put them as `data-label`s and then select them with `"[data-label='"+val+"']"` (optionally with escaping in case `'` appears in the label...)

Otherwise, you will need to escape the input string properly, which could be a hassle.

Comment: They are real classes and used for other functionalities including css styling. Can you expand on this - Otherwise, you will need to escape the input string properly, which could be a hassle - Thank you. And what is about the "+" symbol that creates this issue?

Comment: The `+` symbol is not a valid character in classes because it has a specific use in applying css. [Here's](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) the relevant documentation.

Comment: @Rich Aaaa... that makes sense.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should try to keep your classes as only alphanumeric names. Some symbol characters are valid, but others require that you escape it (prepend a \ before the symbol).

Comment: It's also worth noting that there's nothing stopping you from using `[data-label='tstNavLiThird+']` in your CSS too.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah I was trying to avoid modifying the php/smarty part of the file, but that seems the better approach. Thanks guys.